# How to use Powershell to update the HTTPS cert used by WinRM?

Tags: powershell, windows-server, winrm

#### How to use Powershell to update the HTTPS cert used by WinRM?

I've reviewed the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/system-management-components/configure-winrm-for-https#summary), and they outline how to configure the WinRM cert via the GUI, but they don't illustrate how this would be done in `Powershell`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've already installed the new cert, you can use the script below to configure WinRM to use the new cert.

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    $certThumb
)

Set-WSManInstance -ResourceURI winrm/config/Listener -SelectorSet @{Address="*"; Transport="HTTPS"} -ValueSet @{CertificateThumbprint=$certThumb}
```